# AWS Lambda Ruby on VPC - Seahorse::Client::NetworkingError

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

After adding my Ruby Lambda function to a VPC and attaching the relevant SecurityGroups, I have problems retrieving the SSM credentials for pulling config from aws SSM Parameter Store and I bump into this weird network error after timeout.

This happens when trying to retrieve SSM credentials via `ssm.get_parameters_by_path` but the trace feels like this would have happened on any other AWS call.

```
{
  "errorMessage": "execution expired",
  "errorType": "Function<Seahorse::Client::NetworkingError>",
  "stackTrace": [
    "/var/lang/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/http.rb:937:in `initialize'",
    "/var/lang/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/http.rb:937:in `open'",
    "/var/lang/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/http.rb:937:in `block in connect'",
    "/var/lang/lib/ruby/2.5.0/timeout.rb:103:in `timeout'",
    "/var/lang/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/http.rb:935:in `connect'",
    "/var/lang/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/http.rb:920:in `do_start'",
    "/var/lang/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/http.rb:915:in `start'",
    "/var/lang/lib/ruby/2.5.0/delegate.rb:83:in `method_missing'",
    "/var/runtime/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.40.0/lib/seahorse/client/net_http/connection_pool.rb:297:in `start_session'",
    "/var/runtime/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.40.0/lib/seahorse/client/net_http/connection_pool.rb:96:in `session_for'",
    "/var/runtime/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.40.0/lib/seahorse/client/net_http/handler.rb:121:in `session'",
    "/var/runtime/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.40.0/lib/seahorse/client/net_http/handler.rb:73:in `transmit'",
    "/var/runtime/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.40.0/lib/seahorse/client/net_http/handler.rb:47:in `call'",
    "/var/runtime/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.40.0/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/content_length.rb:12:in `call'",
    "/var/runtime/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.40.0/lib/aws-sdk-core/json/error_handler.rb:8:in `call'",
    "/var/runtime/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.40.0/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/signature_v4.rb:66:in `call'",
    "/var/runtime/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.40.0/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/helpful_socket_errors.rb:10:in `call'",
    "/var/runtime/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.40.0/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/retry_errors.rb:171:in `call'",
    "/var/runtime/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.40.0/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/retry_errors.rb:202:in `retry_request'",
    "/var/runtime/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.40.0/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/retry_errors.rb:185:in `retry_if_possible'",
    "/var/runtime/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.40.0/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/retry_errors.rb:173:in `call'",
    "/var/runtime/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.40.0/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/retry_errors.rb:202:in `retry_request'",
    "/var/runtime/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.40.0/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/retry_errors.rb:185:in `retry_if_possible'",
    "/var/runtime/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.40.0/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/retry_errors.rb:173:in `call'",
    "/var/runtime/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.40.0/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/retry_errors.rb:202:in `retry_request'",
    "/var/runtime/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.40.0/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/retry_errors.rb:185:in `retry_if_possible'",
    "/var/runtime/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.40.0/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/retry_errors.rb:173:in `call'",
    "/var/runtime/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.40.0/lib/aws-sdk-core/json/handler.rb:11:in `call'",
    "/var/runtime/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.40.0/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/user_agent.rb:13:in `call'",
    "/var/runtime/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.40.0/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/endpoint_pattern.rb:28:in `call'",
    "/var/runtime/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.40.0/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/endpoint_discovery.rb:78:in `call'",
    "/var/runtime/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.40.0/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/endpoint.rb:45:in `call'",
    "/var/runtime/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.40.0/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/param_validator.rb:24:in `call'",
    "/var/runtime/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.40.0/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/raise_response_errors.rb:14:in `call'",
    "/var/runtime/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.40.0/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/jsonvalue_converter.rb:20:in `call'",
    "/var/runtime/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.40.0/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/idempotency_token.rb:17:in `call'",
    "/var/runtime/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.40.0/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/param_converter.rb:24:in `call'",
    "/var/runtime/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.40.0/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/response_paging.rb:10:in `call'",
    "/var/runtime/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.40.0/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/response_target.rb:23:in `call'",
    "/var/runtime/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.40.0/lib/seahorse/client/request.rb:70:in `send_request'",
    "/var/runtime/gems/aws-sdk-ssm-1.34.0/lib/aws-sdk-ssm/client.rb:4495:in `get_parameters_by_path'",
```

If I remove the function from the VPC everything runs fine. What went wrong ? (Note that I have added the VPC permission to my lambda role, as well as SSM access)

My SSM client is initialized this way

```
def ssm
  @ssm ||= Aws::SSM::Client.new
end
```

Answer (score 4):

***EDIT***: I had misunderstood the OP's question, so I have edited accordingly trying to explain why it may be failing.

When your Lambda needs to access other AWS Services from within a VPC, your function will need access to your VPC AND to the Internet. This is achievable by attaching both public AND private subnets. The public subnet is the one which has an internet gateway attached to it and therefore can access the public internet and the private subnet is the one that is accessed through a NAT Gateway, visible only inside the AWS VPC.

Also, keep in mind that your Security Groups must allow inbound TCP connections from 0.0.0.0/0 (or just whitelist the host you want to allow).

If you can, avoid putting your Lambda Function inside a VPC as much as you can, since it can increase the cold starts significantly (sometimes it adds 10 seconds on top of your request, which will cause most of your Lambda functions to timeout if not configured properly)

Hope this helps!

***EDIT 2***: I will try to walk you through the process of creating a new VPC through the wizard with two subnets (public and private), allowing the inbound rules on the SG and finally attaching the SNs and the SG to the Lambda function

Please create an Elastic IP beforehand

Through the console, click on VPC, then click on Launch VPC Wizard
[image]

Select VPC with Public and Private Subnets
[image]

Leave the default config and add the Elastic IP you've just created
[image]

Once your VPC is created, you should now have a public and a private subnet
[image]

By default, your SG will already be accepting All Traffic
[image]

Finally, go to your Lambda function and, under the VPC section, add your Subnets and the Security Group.
[image]

And *voilá*, your Lambda should now be able to access the Internet (or other AWS Services)

Comment: Actually I need to put it in my VPC since my lambda is supposed to push some job on a redis queue of one of my instances in my VPC that only allows connection from within specific security groups of the VPC. I don't believe there is anything else I needed to do, since the 0.0.0.0 TPC outbound connections are allowed on all ports. Do you mean that even on the default VPC, my Lambda won't have access to the internet and I need to do something else ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct! The VPC you put your Lambda in needs to have two subnets: a private and a public. You then need to configure both Subnets on your Lambda, under the VPC section. I have released a course on Udemy - which is free - but it's in Portuguese, where I cover exactly this scenario. I think you can just mute and follow along with the videos and see what I do. I use the Serverless Framework to deploy it, but I think it'd give you a rough idea of what needs to be done. https://www.udemy.com/nanosservicos-serverless-orientados-a-eventos/ just start on Lesson 23 and you'll be fine

Comment: In the meantime, I am creating a VPC under my own account with two subnets so I can update my answer with a few screenshots to help you out! Just give me a few minutes, please

Comment: Thanks I understand the problem, I guess I have to make a security compromise of either making my redis instance publicly accessible on the internet so I can use a lambda outside any VPC or play around with VPCs and I'd get the Cold Start overheads anyways... That's a bit sad, but I understand the situation

Comment: Nice! I missed this comment so I ended up editing my answer anyways. Hope it's somehow useful. Good luck!